# How to draw a path in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I developed an android application that show path to user.

I have a list of points that each point contain x,y propery that represent a pixel where i need to draw point.

My Goal is to draw a path from the list of points.
Currently,I am using canvas.DrawCricle() function ,and I get a path but it look like very amateurish and this is problematic.

I want to improve it and get a path that look like more professional.
How can I improve the path visibility?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

When you have no idea about which methods available for some classes, go to developer website, find related class and see which methods available.

In your case;

- go to https://developer.android.com/
- search "Canvas"
- see [drawPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path, android.graphics.Paint)) stands there for your service